# React | ZOD - Form wont submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, zod

I'm trying to submit a form that includes zod validation & schema.
One thing to note is that I have a separate FileInput component that takes care of the image input (gets the URL, later on I'll also get the file itself for the database)
Sorry about the long code..
I have al relevant imports, for some reason, nothing logs to console upon submitting.
I'd love some help.

AddVacation.tsx:

`````
    const [allVacations, setAllVacations] = useState<Vacation[]>([]);
    const [vacImg, setVacImg] = useState<string>();
    function onPreviewChange(previewUrl?: String | undefined): void {
       previewUrl && setVacImg(previewUrl as string);
    }
    type FormData = {
        // id: number,
        destination: string,
        startDate: Date,
        endDate: Date,
        vacDesc: string,
        vacPrice: number,
        vacImg: string,
      }
      // This will be the schema for the form, it'll be used to validate the form when submitting.
      //z.coerce.date() is used to convert the string to a date object.
    const schema: ZodType<FormData> = z.object({
        destination: z.string().min(2, {message: 'Destination must have at least 2 characters'}).nonempty(),
        startDate: z.coerce.date().refine((data) => data > new Date(), {message: 'Start date must be in the future'}),
        endDate: z.coerce.date(),
        vacDesc: z.string().min(2).nonempty(),
        vacPrice: z.number().positive().max(10000),
        vacImg: z.string().nonempty()
        }).refine((data) => data.startDate < data.endDate, {message: 'End date must be after start date',
        path: ['endDate']});
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const { register, handleSubmit, trigger ,formState: { errors } } = useForm<FormData>({resolver: zodResolver(schema)});
        const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
        console.log("submitting...", data)
        console.log(errors);
        const newVacation = new Vacation(data.destination, data.startDate, data.endDate, data.vacDesc, data.vacPrice, data.vacImg);
        console.log(`newVacation: ${newVacation}`)
        const newVacationsArray = [...allVacations, newVacation];
        setAllVacations(newVacationsArray);
        navigate("/vacationList")
      }

    return (
        <div className="AddVacation">
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <form className="addVacationForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Typography variant="h4">Add a new Vacation</Typography>
            <TextField type="text" label="Destination" {...register("destination")} error={!!errors.destination} helperText={errors.destination?.message}
            onBlur={()=>trigger('destination')}/>
            <div>
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">Start Date</Typography>
                <TextField type="date" {...register("startDate")} error={!!errors.startDate} helperText={errors.startDate?.message} 
                onBlur={() => trigger('startDate')}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">End Date</Typography>
                <TextField type="date" {...register("endDate")} error={!!errors.endDate} helperText={errors.endDate?.message}
                onBlur={() => trigger('endDate')}/>
            </div>
            <TextField multiline minRows={1} type="text" label="Description" {...register('vacDesc')}/>
            {/* using valueAsNumber because the TextField component returns a string, and the schema requires a number. */}
            <TextField type="number" label="Price" {...register('vacPrice', {valueAsNumber: true})}
            InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
                ),
            }} error={!!errors.vacPrice} helperText={errors.vacPrice ? errors.vacPrice.message : ''} onBlur={() => trigger('vacPrice')}
            />
            <FileInput onPreviewChange={onPreviewChange} {...register('vacImg', {value: vacImg})}/>
            <Button variant="contained" size="large" color="primary" type="submit"><Typography>Add Vacation</Typography></Button> <br />
            </form>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

and this is the FileInput.tsx:
interface FileInputProps {
    onPreviewChange: (previewUrl?: String) => void;
}

function FileInput({onPreviewChange}: FileInputProps): JSX.Element {
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<File>();
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string>(); //this is the URL of the image

    const handleImageChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const selectedFile = e.target.files?.item(0);
        if (selectedFile) {
            setSelectedImage(selectedFile);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            if (selectedImage) {
                setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage));
                onPreviewChange(URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage));
            } else {
                onPreviewChange(undefined);
            }
    }, [selectedImage,  onPreviewChange]);
    return (
        <div className="FileInput">
            <input accept="image/*" type="file" id="select-img" style={{display: 'none'}} onChange={handleImageChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="select-img">
                <Button variant="outlined" component="span">Choose Image</Button>
                    {selectedImage && (<Box mt={2}>
                    <img src={preview} alt={selectedImage?.name} style={{height:'100px'}}/>
                </Box>
                )}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}````
`````